# Expressjs API variables undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

i'm trying to create my first API using nodejs / express js for backend and React for frontend. I'm able to call the API via postman but not via localhost on frontend as the path returns "undefined" and my "mediaType" and "id" are undefined.

The frontend should call the API

BACKEND

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
const axios = require("axios");

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  // const { mediaType, id } = req.params;
  const { mediaType, id } = req.body;

  const options = {
    methond: "GET",
    url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${mediaType}/${id}?api_key=${APIKEY}&language=en-US`,
    // headers: {

    // }
  };

    axios.request(options).then((response) => {
        res.send(response.data);
    
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  

});
```

FRONTEND

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:8080/test`, { params: { mediaType: mediaType, id: id  } }
    );

    setContent(data);
    
  };
```

PART OF HEADER

```
_header: 'GET /3/undefined/undefined?api_key=XXX&language=en-US HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
    'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
    'User-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r\n' +
    'Host: api.themoviedb.org\r\n' +
    'Connection: close\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
```

Comment: its a GET request, `req.body` should be `req.query`

Answer (score -1):

You accept `body` parameters in your API endpoint
so with axios you should use `data` parameter with your body data included and send it to your backend:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
const { data } = await axios.get(
  `http://localhost:8080/test`, { data: { mediaType: mediaType, id: id  } } <--- check data key here
);

setContent(data);

};
```

by the way, it's not a good idea to send body HTTP request with GET http verb

Comment: its not a good idea because it wont work

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Actually it works ! you can send a body with GET, but, it is never useful to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, for anyone interested...

i updated the FE req

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(   
         `http://localhost:8080/test2?mediaType=${mediaType}&id=${id}`
    );
    setContent(data);
      };
```

And changed the BE req also, to use query parameters

```
      app.get("/test2", (req, res) => {
          // const { mediaType, id } = req.params;
        
          mediaType = req.query.mediaType;
          id = req.query.id;
        
          const options = {
            methond: "GET",
            url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/${mediaType}/${id}?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US`,
            // headers: {
        
            //

 }
      };
    
      axios
        .request(options)
        .then((response) => {
          res.send(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

**Also needed to update CORS (no idea how it works????) as it blocked my localhost testing**

```
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true, //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus: 200,
  })
);
```

Now it seems that everything works!